# Qt QML spotlights effect

Tags: qt, qml

Is it possible to get multiple spotlights using `QtGraphicalEffects` somehow?

The checkered parts below the transparent gradient is a placeholder for any QML `Item`-like type. So the end result could be a complete scene with animated items running underneath the effect.

I've only been able to come up with a solution that uses an `Image` type with 4 `Rectangle` types anchored to the parent container and the `Image` - but with this approach I can only have one spotlight *overlay* on the scene at any one time

[image: Spotlight effect]

I'd like it so I could have multiple spotlights over one scene that blend nicely:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally use a `ShaderEffect` with a simple shader which darkens the output as the distance from the center increases. That would be cheaper than using textures, as it will require none. If you want multiple spotlights, just create multiple instances of the shader effect. You can parameterize and animate the falloff and also add stuff like colorization or variable intensity for stuff like flickering effects.

You will have to render to scene item to a texture, for which you can use simply `ShaderEffectSource`. Then you will actually need to hide the scene, in order to show a black background that's behind it. Then you will have to pass that texture to each shader, which will "reveal" pixels which are in the proximity to the center of the spotlight. If you don't want complete black, you can use opacity to tune down the scene, but not on the scene item directly, but on a parent container item, in order to leave the texture source fully opaque.

Comment: Thanks! Shaders did cross my mind - the big problem is that I don't understand them very well - and I have a hard time just getting examples from the net running via QML - maybe you could post a working (QML) example with your answer?

Comment: I am currently rather busy, maybe later (like in a few days) I will post an example. However understanding shaders is not that complex and a usable skill to have. QML is not a requirement for shaders, you can learn the two in parallel.

Comment: I know but the vast majority of examples around the net is based on e.g. [webGL](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/Mlt3Df) using sites that hides away some of the basic stuf - where you've got both fragColor and fragCoord in same main etc. - it's confusing to me because the QML `ShaderEffect` has these divided (via fragmentShader and vertexShader strings holding the code) - but the examples on e.g. shadertoy has both available